# Unserialize issue php

Tags: php

I am using the following to serialize a variable in php

```
$sum=30;
$a = serialize($sum);
file_put_contents('store', $a);
```

And in another page i am not able to get the variable by unserialize function.In my local
   server ,it is working fine.But when i transferred to live server,i am not able to get the    unserialized variable.I am using following for unserialization,

```
$s = file_get_contents('store');
$a = unserialize($s);
```

What is the issue?

Comment: Have you enabled `error_reporting` yet? (Since something isn't working.)

Comment: do you have enough permissions on the folder you are working, may be write permission are not there and there fore your store file is not getting created there

Comment: so what to do create store file in server?

Comment: store file is creating in server.The issue is with unserialize

Comment: try saving data in store.txt instead of just store

Answer (score 2):

General cases are:

1. Invalid access rights for the file `store`, so a live server isn't able to read a data from it.
2. Different serialization mechanisms on servers. Do you use an `igbinary` or `suhoshin` extensions? They can influence on serialization/unserialization process.
3. Buggy version of PHP. For example, PHP versions from 5.4.6 to 5.4.11 have a lot of bugs with broken serialization.
4. And the last one case is an invalid path to the file, check carefully that this file exists and readable by checking `is_readable('store');`